# Keyboard Buffer F8 key now needs to be pressed twice

Tags: powershell

I use the F8 key a lot to cycle through the list of old commands that begin with what I have typed in the Powershell shell.

Lately, nothing happens if I press the F8 key after typing a few characters of a command. I have to press F8 again before the first match is shown.

Has something changed?

The version I am now using is pwsh 6.2.2. I have been using the same shell for some time, but I am unaware whether version 6.2.2 was a silent upgrade from a previous version.

Comment: Nope, nothing has changed. This has to be environmental on your host.

Comment: To be able to make a statement on that, you should at least post your current PowerShell version and if possible also your previous PowerShell version.